# How do I check if the same key exists in an Array?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, plist

I am trying to make a RPG game in IOS, with a similar dialogue system in Baldurs Gate. I have created two arrays in a plist file. Like this:

[image: Plist file]

As you can see I have two arrays: PlayerMessage; a list (it will be) of multiple choices that the player can touch and NPCMessages; the text that is displayed when the PlayerMessage is touched

I am at the stage where I can touch on the NPC and it will display a black box (NPCMessageer node) with text from the array (PlayerMessage via the plist file).

However, I don't know how to connect Item 0 in PlayerMessage and NPC Message and if they exist change the Message: SKLabelNode! text to one in NPCMessage. Does anyone know how to compare if another item exist in another array?

Here is the code that I have used:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    
    for touch in (touches) {
        
        NPC.name = "NPC"
        
        let Location = touch.location(in: self)
                    
                    var CorrectedLocation = CGPoint()
                    CorrectedLocation.x = Location.x - LocalCamera.position.x
                    CorrectedLocation.y = Location.y - LocalCamera.position.y

        let node = self.atPoint(CorrectedLocation)
        var Message: SKLabelNode!
        Message = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Trebuchet MS")

        if (node.name == "NPC") {
            let NPCMessageer = SKSpriteNode (color: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width:1000, height:1000))
            NPCMessageer.zPosition = 99
            NPCMessageer.position = CGPoint(x:-500, y:-200)
          Message.fontSize = 50
            Message.color = UIColor.white;            Message.position = CGPoint(x:-500, y:-100)
            Message.zPosition = 100

            addChild(NPCMessageer)
            self.addChild(Message)
            for PlayerMessage in NPC.PlayerMessage {
             Message.text = PlayerMessage as?String}
            let label = self.atPoint(CorrectedLocation)
            if label.name == "Message"
            {
                
                
             if NPC.PlayerMessage == NPC.NPCMessage
             {
                Message.text = NPC.NPCMessage as?String
             }
```

Comment: I find it very hard to understand this question, do I have to know SpriteKit to understand it or could you perhaps clarify what you are asking? Off-topic but variables should start with a lowercase letter, your code is a bit hard to read as it is.

Comment: Fair comment. I'll reword it.  I did not know that variables need to start with a lowercase. Does that apply to all languages?

Comment: @LaurensvanOorschot They don;t *have* to, but its common practice to use 'Camel Case' i.e. thisIsMyUserVariable as many iOS elements start with a capital and this distinguishes them. Camel Case for variables is common across a lot of programming languages, Even use it for acronyms in variables i.e. myNpcMessage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to find a given element from one array in another array.

You can then use `firstIdex(of:)` and if an element exist use the returned index to set the Message object

```
let item = PlayerMessage[0] //assuming this is what you want to find

if let index = NPCMessage.firstIndex(of: item) {
    let Message.text = NPCMessage[index]
}
```